# Margin Issue in IE11

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code that adds a span to input elements on load, event handlers are then added to capture click and blur events, but this is beside the point. The issue is that in IE11 the dynamically added span does not display the left margin within the parent element (the input field) but displays it (the 24px left margin) to the left of the input, Firefox 29.0 and Chrome 34.0.1847.131 shows the margin within the input field so giving an indent which pushes the text in span past the inputs background image. Any ideas why IE is doing this?

On Load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text][title],input[type=password][title],textarea[title]').each(function(i)
  {
    $(this).addClass('input-prompt-' + i);
    var promptSpan = $('<span class="input-prompt"/>');
    $(promptSpan).attr('id', 'input-prompt-' + i);
    $(promptSpan).append($(this).attr('title'));

    $(promptSpan).click(function(){
      $(this).hide();
      $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).focus();
    });

    if($(this).val() != ''){
      $(promptSpan).hide();
    }

    $(this).before(promptSpan);
    $(this).focus(function()
    {
      $('#input-prompt-' + i).hide();
    });

    $(this).blur(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
        $('#input-prompt-' + i).show();
        $('#input-prompt-' + i).css('display', 'inline')
      }
    });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>
<input type="password" title="Password" name="password" id="mPass" />
<div class="notice" id="ePass"></div>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
#mPass {
    background:#fff url('../img/pass.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 4px 9px;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 2em;
}

.input-prompt {
    position: absolute;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #aaa;
    margin: 0.9em 0 0 24px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid to have a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` element. This is the most likely cause of your problem.

Comment: Removed them, it's not that as it makes no difference at all.